# $f$ is an entire function and there are $a,b$ such that $f(z+w_1)=af(z)$ and $f(z+w_2)=bf(z)$. Show that $f=Ae^{Bz}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I was doing my homework:

> If $w_1, w_2\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $\mathrm{Im}\frac{w_1}{w_2}\neq0$ , $f$ is an entire function and  there are $a,b$ such that
>
> \begin{array}{ll}
>             f(z+w_1)=af(z) \\
>             f(z+w_2)=bf(z)
> \end{array}
>
> Show that $f=Ae^{Bz}$.

I gave the following solution and my teacher said that is wrong and I don't know why.

If  $f$ has no zeros, then $\frac{f'}{f}$ is double period entire function and hence $\frac{f'}{f}=B$, so $f=Ae^{Bz}$.

For the general case, according the previous discussion, $g=e^{Bz}$ sastifies

\begin{array}{ll}
            g(z+w_1)=ag(z) \\
            g(z+w_2)=bg(z)
       \end{array}

so $\frac{f}{g}$ is double period entire funciton and hence $f=Ag$, i.e, $f=Ae^{Bz}$.

I don't understand why my solution is wrong. I am wondering if anyone could point the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is it true that if $f\not \equiv 0,$ then $f'/f$ is entire?

Comment: From $f\not\equiv 0$ it does not follow that $f$ has no zeros. So $\frac{f'}{f}$ may have poles. You need to show that here, it doesn't. For the other, you need to show that there is a $B$ such that $e^{Bw_1} = a$ and $e^{Bw_2} = b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry about the wrong notations, here $f\not\equiv0$ means that $f$ doesn't have zeros. And I think the first part in my solution is working on the existence of such B

Comment: @DanielFischer Unforunately there doesn't have to be B such $e^{Bw_1}=a$ and $e^{Bw_2}=b$ in general. In fact, if so, then it can only leads to f=0

Answer (score 0):

From
\begin{align}f(z+w_1)&=af(z)\\f(z+w_2)&=bf(z)\end{align}
it follows that
\begin{align}f(z+w_1)e^{-\frac{\log(a)}{w_1}(z+w_1)}&=e^{-\frac{\log(a)}{w_1}(z+w_1)}e^{\log(a)}f(z)\\f(z+w_2)e^{-\frac{\log(b)}{w_2}(z+w_2)}&=e^{-\frac{\log(b)}{w_2}(z+w_2)}e^{\log(b)}f(z)\end{align}
and
\begin{align}f(z+w_1)e^{-\frac{\log(a)}{w_1}(z+w_1)}&=e^{-\frac{\log(a)}{w_1}z}f(z)\\f(z+w_2)e^{-\frac{\log(b)}{w_2}(z+w_2)}&=e^{-\frac{\log(b)}{w_2}z}f(z).\end{align}

Rewriting gives
\begin{align}f(z+w_1)e^{-\frac{\log(a)}{w_1}(z+w_1)}&=e^{-\frac{\log(a)}{w_1}z}f(z)\\f(z+w_2)e^{-\frac{\log(b)}{w_2}(z+w_2)}&=e^{-\frac{\log(b)}{w_2}z}f(z)\end{align}

Excuse me, I don't know the answer yet. Hopefully an edit follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if I don't quite understand how the matrix B appears, this answer can indeed impies if f has a zero, then f vanshished everywhere. But why my answer is wrong?

Comment: I take a close look at your answer and I don't think $f(z+\lambda_1 w_1)=a^{\lambda_1}f(z)$ can be deduced from the condition.